# Android - Google Map make marker sticky

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have following marker code on my MapFragment. I want this marker stick to it's position. Means I want marker at center position in map and when I move/drag map then marker shouldn't get moved. How to do that with following marker?

```
PlaceMarker = PlaceMap.addMarker(
                            new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                            .draggable(true)
                            .title("Drag Me"));

            PlaceMarker.showInfoWindow();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a listener when the user pans the map and set the marker on the center.

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {   
            mMap.clear();               
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cameraPosition.target));
        }
});
```

Another way of doing this is by overlaying a marker icon (Not a real marker; defined in your XML layout) and get the location when the user sets that as a location.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to set [draggable](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setDraggable(boolean)) to false

```
public void setDraggable (boolean draggable)
```

The sets the draggability of the marker.

Comment: No...! Draggable marker doesn't matter here. If I set Draggable false, still when I drag to Map then marker getting moved.