# How to make an overlay over map

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to create an overlay over map so that when map is scrolled the center/marker will be fixed and i can get Location data from that point.Take a look at image for what i want to achieve.
[image]
 I google a lot Please Suggest me little  how to achieve this functionality.I don't think it's possible using ground overlay.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473652/android-google-map-make-marker-sticky/29939260#29939260

Comment: @AC-OpenSource Exactly what i was looking for.I was just missing the right term while searching Kudo.